# How to send a transaction using bytes32 from python to an ethereum private network?

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, web3py

I've generated the following code to transact against my private network and I've implemented the following python script:

```
import sys, os, time
from solc import compile_source, compile_files, link_code
from ethjsonrpc import EthJsonRpc

print("Using enviroment in " + sys.prefix)
print("Python version " + sys.version)

c = EthJsonRpc('127.0.0.1', 8042)
c.web3_clientVersion()

params = [1,2,3,4,5,6,b'0x2a706b3187db623b309cd7e8a8c15308160600d68b8eae590978a32ad6c967b2']
tx = c.call_with_transaction(c.eth_coinbase(),'0x1e291B2CDB574519Ee1c3d75CA849f34153EE9e5', 'post(uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,bytes32)', params)
```

When I execute the script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write_raspberry_v1.py", line 15, in <module>
    tx = c.call_with_transaction(c.eth_coinbase(),'0x1e291B2CDB574519Ee1c3d75CA849f34153EE9e5', 'post(uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,uint8,bytes32)', params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ethjsonrpc/client.py", line 127, in call_with_transaction
    data = self._encode_function(sig, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ethjsonrpc/client.py", line 78, in _encode_function
    encoded_params = encode_abi(types, param_values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ethereum/abi.py", line 369, in encode_abi
    myhead += enc(proctypes[i], args[i])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ethereum/abi.py", line 344, in enc
    return utils.to_string(encode_single(typ, arg))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ethereum/abi.py", line 211, in encode_single
    assert len(arg) <= int(sub)
```

How can I solute this? Is there another way to send a transaction from python to my private network (using web3 directly?)

Version using web3.py:

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8042"))

vinduino = w3.eth.contract(
    address = "0x1e291B2CDB574519Ee1c3d75CA849f34153EE9e5",
    abi = contract_interface['abi'],
)

tx_hash = vinduino.functions.post(1,2,3,4,5,6,"0x2a706b3187db623b309cd7e8a8c15308160600d68b8eae590978a32ad6c967b2").call({'from': w3.eth.coinbase})

print(tx_hash)
```

Comment: This `assert len(arg) <= int(sub)` failed, meaning that probably the `encode_single` method on the file `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ethereum/abi.py` is expecting less arguments than it is receiving.

Comment: You said "using web3 directly," but you don't appear to be using web3.py. Is it a requirement that you stick with `EthJsonRpc`? Or can you use web3.py? (If you use web3.py, just pass a `bytes`, although I believe a hexadecimal string will also work.)

Comment: Yes smarx, I want to make this transaction using web3.py but as it wasn't working I tried EthJsonRpc. I update the post to add the web3.py code ASAP, it is giving an out of gas problem but when I execute the same function from Ethereum Wallet it doesn't.